# Incrementing arrays in C,SPECIAL CASE

Tags: c, arrays

I am confused by the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[] = {5, 15, 1, 20, 25};
    int i, j, m;

    i = ++a[1];   /*statement 1*/
    j = a[1]++;   /*statement 2*/
    m = a[i++];   /*statement 3*/

    printf("\n%d\n%d\n%d\n", i, j, m);

    return 0;
}
```

Statements 1, 2, 3 are a bit confusing for me; I don't not get the way these are producing the output for me. Can anyone shed some light on this please?

Comment: Is this missing the homework tag?

Comment: :-o @Redx THIS IS NOT MY HOME WORK  AT ALL........:-)

Comment: This test requires either (1) a C compiler or (2) a pretty good knowledge the effect the post-increment operator would have on the expression being evaluated and its side-effect of the variables post-incremented. Possibly both! Even a seasoned C programmer would probably prefer a pen and paper to help them solve it. I'd take it as a caution as to how side-effect operators can make code hard to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
i=++a[1];   /*statement 1*/   // increments the value of a[1] and assigns to i
j=a[1]++;   /*statement 2*/   // assign the value of a[i] and then increments the value of a[i] to j
m=a[i++];   /*statement 3*/   //  assign a[i] to m, and increment i


i=++a[1];   // a[1] is 15 here so i =16, and a[1] =16
j=a[1]++;   // a[1] is 16 so j =16 and a[1] =17
m=a[i++];   // i is 16 here but index 16 does not exists here, so program fails
```

Comment: The last one is not correct. it assigns a[i] to m and then increments i.

Comment: Plus it will fail in the example of Alfred Nobel because it would point to a[6]

Comment: Doesn't it point to a[16] ? Well out of bounds. Plus 'k' is never used.

Comment: @GAURAV:in statement 2,are you saying that,j will have the value of a[1],& a[1] will get incremented?

Comment: @Alfred Nobel : a[1]++ is same as a[1] = a[1] + 1

Comment: Weird... apparently 'k' has since disappeared from the code. Self-modifying code?

Answer (score 2):

```
i = ++a[1];   /*statement 1*/
```

Hear a[1] will be 15. and Pre Increment operator will increase a[1] with 1 S0 `i will be 16`

```
j = a[1]++;   /*statement 2*/
```

Post increment operator will also increment the value of a[1] by 1. so `j will be 16`.

```
m = a[i++];   /*statement 3*/
```

Here, it is i++, so post increment oprator will increase i by 1..earlier i was computed 16  . now `i will now be 17`.

```
So a[17] has no value. so m will be junk value
```

Comment: The last one is not correct. it assigns a[i] to m and then increments i.

Answer (score 0):

The First Statement

`i = ++a[1]` ---> Increments the value of a[1] (i.e) i value will be 16

Second Statement

`j = a[1]++`  ---> Assign the value of a[1] to j and then incremented(i.e) j would be 16.

Third Statement

`m = a[i++]`  --> Assigning value of a[i] to m and i is incremented.

Comment: a[1] is incremented in first statement so it would be 16 in second statement.

Answer (score 0):

In case of doubt, what you can do is use gdb:

1. Compile your code setting debug flag (-g for gcc) `gcc -g -o so stackoverflow.c`
2. run gdb `gdb ./so`
3. identify lines to break `list` in gdb
4. set breakpoints `break 6` (first break is line 6)
5. Step forward `step`
6. Display values `print i` or `print a[1]` for instance.

But beware, if you call `print ++a[1]` in gdb you may change your program behaviour!